# Unity touch/mouse collide instead of MouseDown()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sprite which at the moment I detect the mouse click on it.

However I really need to detect when the finger or mouse touches or moves across the sprite because the finger/mouse click event will occur somewhere else on the screen and not on top of the sprite.

```
public class Hand : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            this.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
I tried to detect both touching the sprite and the mouse is down but I dont get the button clicked. I can remove the `&& Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` and it will work if the mouse moves over but I want both mouse/finger over the sprite and the pressed down.

```
private void Update()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000) && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        hit.collider.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Could you try rephrasing your question, i am having a hard time understanding what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question. Hopefully it is a little clearer.

Comment: Sounds like you will need to RayCast from the touch point if its moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 possible solution :

First: Instead of just using sprites, use button and assign it to world space canvas, in 
       this case touch should work if you assign canva's event camera to main camera.

2nd :If u just want to use sprites, then assign a collider to it, and use raycast

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position); 
           if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,1000))
                hit.collider.gameobject.GetComponent<Button>.onClick().Invoke();
```

Edit : The above code will work if you have a button component attached to your sprite. if not
Just call something like this

```
if(hit.collider.gameobject.GetComponenet<Sprite>())
   DoWhateverYouWant()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the 2nd option is the best for my use case. Just to be clear do I attached the `Ray` to the `Update` of the sprite?

Comment: first, I've edited my answer ,

2nd clear things up for you. lets say we have a script called "TouchController.cs", and you write down the similar logic at its UpdateFunction. then you attach this script to any gameobject in the scene and you should start it on the phone. bec it will not work on your PC, also make sure you check for If TouchCount is more than 0

Comment: I would need a solution that would work with both mouse and touch unfortunately

Comment: I have update my question with what I think you are say. I have added a button component

Comment: you can do something like 
#If Unity_Android
then add ur logic with touch
#endif

while then u can add normal code for your mouse position.

Check this out : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the EventSystem interfaces to detect any kind mouse interaction with UI elements.

The EventSystem interfaces are listed [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SupportedEvents.html).

For example, if you want to detect when the mouse hovers over a sprite, you would add a script to the sprite object like so:

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseOverHandler: MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
   public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData data){
        Debug.Log("MouseEnter");
   }

   public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData data){
        Debug.Log("MouseExit");
   }
}
```

Note that the EventSystem works with the raycaster on the associated sprite's canvas. So if sprites are sitting on top of eachother, they can block raycasts and so the PointEnter event only gets triggered on the topmost sprite