# Cloning too many of the same object when pressing an object to replace instead of the other

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[image: Image from my 2D game on unity cloning infinite objects when I press the broken one]

I want to replace the broken table with a fixed table but when I press the button it places the table multiple times around the background. This is the script for the replacement.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReplaceObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Broken_Table;
    public GameObject Table;
    private bool used = false;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()

    {

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            GameObject broken_Table = Instantiate(Broken_Table) as GameObject;
            GameObject table = Instantiate(Table) as GameObject;
            Replace(broken_Table, table);
            used = true;
        }

    }
    void Replace(GameObject obj1, GameObject obj2)
    {

        Instantiate(obj2, obj1.transform.position, obj1.transform.rotation);
        Destroy(obj1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating 3 objects for every frame you have input.

```
            GameObject broken_Table = Instantiate(Broken_Table) as GameObject;
            GameObject table = Instantiate(Table) as GameObject;
```

and

```
            Instantiate(obj2, obj1.transform.position, obj1.transform.rotation);
```

All of the above statements clone objects into your scene. You're then destroying the broken_Table right after creating it, meaning you're creating 2 fixed tables for every frame your finger is held down.

To fix this, you can do both of the following things:

1. Only enact logic on the first frame your player "touches" the object, rather than every frame. The best way to do this is to utilize the [GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) method and only act during TouchPhase.Began.
2. Do not instantiate more than 1 "fixed table" in this code.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not trying to hold the touch but I'm trying to make the broken table get replaced by the new one in the same position where the broken one is. another issue is, that I want to press on the object itself, not the screen. i don't know why stuff happens when I touch the screen not the object even with the existence of the 2D collider

Comment: Input.touchCount includes all input to Unity, not just on the current object. If you want to check for touches, you'll want to take a look at a few other strategies like OnMouseDown or [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008971/unity-touch-mouse-collide-instead-of-mousedown)

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be called every frame while your touchcount is superior than zero.
So as long as you hold your finger on the screen it will call the Replace() method.

You can add your "used" bool to the previous if to avoid that, like so:

```
 void Update()

    {

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && !used)
        {
            Replace(broken_Table, table);
            used = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, I did this. But now when I try to click it clones once but the object is not in place of the broken table. and it doesn't destroy the broken table, meaning it doesn't disappear from the scene and get replaced with the new table.